# Check if an item exists in an observableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Why is the check for duplicate `Artist` always returning `false`?

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jkittell/8x6c505o/1/) for a runnable demo.

**Knockout Code**

```
$(function() {

  function Artist(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.favoriteArtists = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.artistToAdd = ko.observableArray("");
    self.addArtist = function () {
      var newFavoriteArtist = new Artist(self.artistToAdd());
      console.log("New Favorite Artist: " + newFavoriteArtist.name);
      var artistExists = self.favoriteArtists.indexOf(newFavoriteArtist) > 0;
      console.log("Artist Exists: " + artistExists);
      if(!artistExists) {
          self.favoriteArtists.push(newFavoriteArtist);
          console.log("A new artist has been added:" + self.artistToAdd());
      } else {
        console.log("Artist already in favorites.");
      }
    };
  }  
  ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
});
```

**HTML**

```html
<h1>Favorite Artists</h1>
<p>Currently, your favorite artists include:</p>
<ul data-bind="foreach: favoriteArtists">
    <li> <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
<p>Enter the name of a new artist:</p>
<input data-bind="value: artistToAdd" />
<button data-bind="click: addArtist">Add</button>
```

Comment: Why are you using an `observableArray`?

Comment: @KSFT You are right, `self.artistToAdd` should be `ko.observable("")' and NOT `ko.observableArray("")`, that was what was causing the check to always return false.

Comment: Okay, but why is `favoriteArtists` an `observableArray` instead of a normal array?

Comment: @KSFT I data-bind the observable array in the html source to display the list of `Artist` items in the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure, but 
self.favoriteArtists.indexOf(newFavoriteArtist) > 0;
seems a bit strange, I expect a -1 there. If you add the same artist constantly it will keep thinking it did not exist.

And you keep making new objects, that are not in the list. (complex) objects are not equal to eachother by default.

Comment: Wups, overlooked your answer. This is correct IMHO. You could include [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x4t5yo3z/) and possibly a snippet of its code too.

Answer (score 8):

Your check should be one of these:

```
self.favoriteArtists.indexOf(newFavoriteArtist) >= 0

self.favoriteArtists.indexOf(newFavoriteArtist) != -1

self.favoriteArtists.indexOf(newFavoriteArtist) > -1
```

You're checking whether it's greater than zero. That means that if it's in position 0, `artistExists` will be set to `false` because zero is not greater than zero.

That still doesn't work, though. The array is filled with `Artist` objects, which can't be searched for normally, because the object you search for is different from the object in the array, even if they have the same `name` value.

Answer (score 3):

You can filter the array and check to see if its length is zero. If it is not empty, it contains the item.

```
return favoriteArtists.filter(function(data) {
      return data === newFavoriteArtist;
    }).length !== 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this part of code:

```
var newFavoriteArtist = new Artist(self.artistToAdd());
// ...
var artistExists = self.favoriteArtists.indexOf(newFavoriteArtist) > 0;
```

Each time you create a new object (`new Artist`). Then you're trying to find new object in a list of old objects (`favoriteArtists`) - and here your code doesn't work as expected.

Instead you could add some another function, which allows you to find artist by name (or some other unique property) and clarify whether this item was added before.

Answer (score 0):

Better is to stop iterating after first element is found instead of go through all collection (so use find, not filter):

```
return favoriteArtists.find(function(data) {
  return data === newFavoriteArtist;
}) !== null;
```